# Tkinter/Python - Show new label from a list after action/click from a button

Tags: python, tkinter

im new to this world of programmring and decided to learn some python. Im currently working on a project with the tkinter package where i want to show a label (A string from a list) and then when clicked on a button, delete that current label and show the next label without destroying the window. As im new in this field im really stuck on how to move on, when trying different approaches i seem to only succed showing the first string from the list of strings, or all the strings.

I tried to make it work without tkinter first of course, with a I/O type code and came up with something like this:

```
listOfNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

for item in listOfNumbers:
    print(item)
    reactionInput = input("Is this a number?: Y = Yes \n")
    if reactionInput == "Y":
        continue
```

Do you have any tips on how to apply this above, in tkinter to get it work with button instead of an input like above and continue with next string in tkinter window when button is clicked? Or if there is a better way without tkinter?

Comment: You could change the text of the existing label.

Comment: You could easily do what you want with tkinter. There are many tutorials that would walk you through the steps. Your `input` could be replaced with an `Entry` and you could use a function with a `Button` and then display information on a `Labe`.  What have you tried? There isn't any `Tk` in your sample code.